# Setting the DataContext on an Entity instance after it's retrieved

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to find a way to have the DataContext available from within Entities.

I want to do something like this:

```
partial public class MyEntity

    public DataContext as MyDataContext

    private sub OnLoaded()
        Me.DataContext = <the context that retrieved this instance>
    end sub

end class
```

First, can something like this be done?
Second, assuming that I'm not going to use this entity with any other DataContext, is there any dangers or gotchas in doing such a thing?

This is the way I do it currently:

```
partial public class MyDataContext

    public function GetMyEntity(byval id as integer) as MyEntity
        dim o = MyEntities.SingleOrDefault(function(e) e.id = id)
        if o isnot nothing then o.DataContext = Me
        return o
    end function

end class
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Why do you need the datacontext for each entity?

Comment: In general this seems to be unnecessary and there is probably a better way of doing whatever you want to do. It would help if you provide a more detailed description of your scenario. There might be gotchas depending on how you are planning to use this system. As far as I can see, you have a web-app (references to `HttpContext` in comments). One thing that comes to mind is if you use a per-request or shorter context lifespan, but, say, store your entities in cache and try to retrieve and use them later - you'll get your first problem. I can try to think of more if you describe your scenario.

Comment: I'm not trying to cache anything. I say exactly what I'm trying to do in the question. I simply want to have a reference (from within an entity instance) to the data context that retrieved it. As I've stated in other comments, the lifespan of the data context will be no longer than a web request.

Comment: It's perfectly clear what you want, but you still did not explain how you are going to use this reference to the context on every entity. Only if you provide further details can one think of some possible gotchas you are asking about. And yes, you aren't caching anything now, but your current implementation might prevent you from doing so if you need it at some point later on (it's just an example of a problem you might run into).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a singleton pattern on the DataContext, but you will need some kind of lifetime management on it, as it is not good to keep it around to long. (request ends dispose it maybe)

Example in C#, but I hope you can understand it.

```
public class MyDataContext
{       
    public static MyDataContext Current 
    {
        get
        {
            MyDataContext context = (MyDataContext)HttpContext.Current.Items["Context"];
            if(context == null)
            {
                context = new MyDataContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items["Context"] = context;
            }
            return context;
        }
    }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public MyDataContext DataContext
    {
        get{ return MyDataContext.Current;}
    }
}
```

In Global.asax you can hook up the event `Application_EndRequest` and call `MyDataContext.Current.Dispose();` to dispose of the context manually instead of waiting for the GC to do it.

Comment: I didn't think about putting it in the HttpContext. What's the lifespan of that? I've never used it for anything other than accessing request or session.

Comment: It will end when the request ends. So it is very short

Comment: Is there a way to have a base entity class that every entity will inherit from?

Comment: I think it is possible using templates. Have a look at this project: http://l2st4.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Although you didn't specify a real reason for it, just [a sidenote from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx):

> In general, a `DataContext` instance is
>   designed to last for one "unit of
>   work" however your application defines
>   that term. A `DataContext` is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to
>   create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates `DataContext`
>   instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that
>   represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

and one [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386929%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> Do not try to reuse instances of
>   `DataContext`. Each `DataContext`
>   maintains state (including an identity
>   cache) for one particular edit/query
>   session. To obtain new instances based
>   on the current state of the database,
>   use a new `DataContext`.

and finally,

> ... Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

But still in some cases semi-persistent solutions could be very helpful. Take a look onto Rick Strachl's article: [Linq to SQL DataContext Lifetime Management](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx). There are different approaches of `DataContext` management is reviewed in it. On of them - *Create a per business object DataContext* is exactly what you need.

Comment: My usage of the data context is very short lived. typically only the lifetime of a web request. I could just create a new instance whenever, but i need to access the same context from all my objects (mainly because of the identity cache).